# Scope dependable attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Having model pricing:

```
pricingable_id:integer
pricingable_type:string
**store_id**:integer
cost_price:decimal
margin:integer
discount:integer
active:boolean
```

And one another model products:

```
name
description
...

has_many :pricings, as: :pricingable
```

So, how can I delegate attributes cost_price, margin, discount, active from product to pricing depending to store_id (single)?

Tried something like **has_one :pricing, -> { where store_id: Store.current_id }** but doesn't make sense.

UPD: I need to assign pricing attributes from product model:

```
Store.current_id = 1

p = Product.new
p.cost_price = 100
p.margin = 10
p.discount = 5
p.active = true
p.save

pricing = Product.**pricing** (not pricings, one pricing depending to current store)
pricing.cost_price
=> 100
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest changing your associations.

A Price (changed name from Pricing, which is in my opinion not intuitive) should be associated with Product AND Store.

In this layout everything is super easy, and I think that's what you tried to achieve.

Ex.:

```
Price.where(product_id: Product.first, store_id: 1).cost_price
```

Editing example.

Let's say you have oatmeal product with id 1 in 3 stores: Costco, Walmart & Aldi. (ids 1..3)

If you want to change the price of this product in a giver shop (let's say Walmart), you can do

```
Price.where(store_id: 2, product_id: 1).update {}
```

More examples.

All prices for a given product:

```
Product.first.joins(:prices)
```

All prices in a store (and associated prices):

```
Store.first.joins(products: :prices)
```

Comment: Ok, but I need to change Price attributes from product model, is it possible?

Comment: Ok, I think you are missing something. As far as I understand you don't just change price. You change a Price in a Store (as in real life). So - yes, you can change a price, but you have to join a store first. Adding examples.

Comment: HA, I messed up my example, fixing answer.

Comment: Yep, I'm agree, that price should be associated with product and scope, but I have another question. I'm in need to assign price attributes from product. Take a look at update please. Many thanks.

Comment: I need to read more on that, will try to answer this question tomorrow (it's 11pm in here now), because that's something I wanted to know how to do but never really knew.

Comment: Sorry for the delay (I forgot about it, stupid me). I don't think you can do what you aim at. In math terms Price is a function of Product and Store, I see no way to model associations in such way to fulfil your reqs. You can change relations so that `Store` `has_many :products, through: :price but it doesn't really change the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you want a polymorphic association... please check out this rails guide on the subject:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

Comment: Yep. Pricing is polymorphic, cause different models can has many pricings.

Comment: Great!  Everything you need to know is in that guide.  :)

Comment: But it's not question about polymorphic associations :)

Comment: I believe it is... if you follow the guide, I think you'll find the answer to your question.  You need to set up the appropriate associations and then call them correctly.